# Google sheets says too many users accessing the file but its only a few

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sites

Actually the header says it all. I have a google sheet and in the last two weeks it happens to be "opened by too many users" so that i cannot edit the file or embedded elements of the sheet on a Google Site are not displayed.

I have two ideas what the reason could be, but no idea how to find out:

1. The file itself is on a shared Google Drive, so technically everyone with access to the shared drive has also access to the sheet, but hardly anyone uses it (like 3- 5 users).
2. I have a few scripts accessing the file from time to time, but its on average only one script every 20 minutes.

Does anyone have experienced this issue and also has a solution or maybe just another idea what the problem is?

Thanks in advance,

Sammi

The Code of the functions causing the "Exceptions:Too many.."-Problem (Please be gentle, coding isnt my main field :D): The funcion computes some averages of produced material

```
  function durchschnittAktuellUndLetzte() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen = ss.getSheetByName("Anzeige tägliche Zahlen");
  var anzeige8wochenSchnitt = ss.getSheetByName("Anzeige 8Wochen-Schnitt");
  var i = 4;
  var counterAktuell = 0;
  var summeAktuell = 0;
  while(i<=18){
    var stueckzahlAktuellerTag = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(i,5,1,1).getValue();
    if(stueckzahlAktuellerTag!= ""){
      summeAktuell = summeAktuell + stueckzahlAktuellerTag;
      counterAktuell++;
      i++;
    }
    else{
      i++;
    }
  }
  if(summeAktuell != 0){
    var ausgabeAktuelleNormal = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(3,1,1,1).setValue(summeAktuell/counterAktuell);
    var ausgabeAktuelleInfoansicht = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(9,3,1,1).setValue(summeAktuell/counterAktuell);
    var ausgabeAktuelleMobil = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(15,5,1,1).setValue(summeAktuell/counterAktuell);
  } else{  
    var ausgabeAktuelleNormal =  anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(3,1,1,1).setValue("0");
    var ausgabeAktuelleInfoansicht = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(9,3,1,1).setValue("0");
    var ausgabeAktuelleMobil = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(15,5,1,1).setValue("0");
  }
  var j = 4;
  var counterLetzte = 0;
  var summeLetzte = 0;
  while(j<=18){
    var stueckzahlLetzteTag = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(j,11,1,1).getValue();
      if(stueckzahlLetzteTag!= ""){
        summeLetzte = summeLetzte + stueckzahlLetzteTag;
        counterLetzte++;
        j++;
      }
      else{
        j++;
      }
  }
  if(summeLetzte != 0){
    var ausgabeLetzteNormal = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(5,1,1,1).setValue(summeLetzte/counterLetzte);
    var ausgabeLetzteInfoansicht = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(11,3,1,1).setValue(summeLetzte/counterLetzte);
    var ausgabeLetzteMobil = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(17,5,1,1).setValue(summeLetzte/counterLetzte);
  } else{
    var ausgabeLetzteNormal = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(5,1,1,1).setValue("0");
    var ausgabeLetzteInfoansicht = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(11,3,1,1).setValue("0");
    var ausgabeLetzteMobil = anzeige8wochenSchnitt.getRange(17,5,1,1).setValue("0");
  }
}
```

THe second one: This function copys data and writes some values for format changes of a production line

```
    function tabellenwochenweise() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var dateneingabe = ss.getSheetByName("Dateneingabe");
    var anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen = ss.getSheetByName("Anzeige tägliche Zahlen");
    var auswertung = ss.getSheetByName("Auswertung");
    var stueckzahlenaktuelleKW = dateneingabe.getRange(8,10,15,1).getValues();
    var chargenwechselAktuell = dateneingabe.getRange(8,13,15,1).getValues();
    var formatAktuell = dateneingabe.getRange(8,11,15,1).getValues();
    var arrayUebertragAktuell = [];
    var uebertragaktuell = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,5,15,1).setValues(stueckzahlenaktuelleKW);
    var aktuellMobileAnsicht = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,17,15,1).setValues(stueckzahlenaktuelleKW);
    var anzeigeKWaktuell = dateneingabe.getRange(3,10,1,1).getValue();
    var uebertragKWaktuell = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,2,1,1).setValue(anzeigeKWaktuell);
    var uebertragKWaktuellMobil = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,14,1,1).setValue(anzeigeKWaktuell);
    //vergangene KW:
    var stueckzahlenvergangeneKW = dateneingabe.getRange(8,1,15,1).getValues();
    var chargenwechselVergangene = dateneingabe.getRange(8,5,15,1).getValues();
    var formatVergangene = dateneingabe.getRange(8,3,15,1).getValues();
    var arrayUebertragVergangene = [];
    var uebertragVergangene = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,11,15,1).setValues(stueckzahlenvergangeneKW);
    var vergangeneMobileAnsicht = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,23,15,1).setValues(stueckzahlenvergangeneKW);
    var anzeigeKWvergangene = anzeigeKWaktuell - 1;
    var uebertragKWvergangene = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,8,1,1).setValue(anzeigeKWvergangene);
    var uebertragKWvergangeneMobil = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,20,1,1).setValue(anzeigeKWvergangene);
    //array für Chargenwechsel aktuelle Woche
    var arraychargenwechselaktuell = [];
      arraychargenwechselaktuell.push(chargenwechselAktuell); 
    //array für Format aktuelle Woche
    var arrayformataktuell = [];
    arrayformataktuell.push(formatAktuell);  
      for(var j = 0; j<formatAktuell.length;j=j+1){    
        if(formatAktuell[j][0]==="--" || formatAktuell[j][0]===""){
          arrayUebertragAktuell.push(arraychargenwechselaktuell[0][j]);        
        }
        else{
          arraychargenwechselaktuell[0][j];
          var moment = arraychargenwechselaktuell[0][j];
          moment = +moment;
          moment++;
          arrayUebertragAktuell.push([moment]);      
        }
      }
    //Ausgabe   
    var uebertragFormatundChargenwechselAktuell = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,6,15,1);
    uebertragFormatundChargenwechselAktuell.setValues(arrayUebertragAktuell);
    var uebertragFormatundChargenwechselAktuellMobil = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,18,15,1);
    uebertragFormatundChargenwechselAktuellMobil.setValues(arrayUebertragAktuell);
    //array für Chargenwechsel vergangene Woche
        var arraychargenwechselVergangene = [];
            arraychargenwechselVergangene.push(chargenwechselVergangene); 
        //array für Format vergangene Wochewechse
        var arrayformatVergangene = [];
          arrayformatVergangene.push(formatVergangene);  
          for(var j = 0; j<formatVergangene.length;j=j+1){    
            if(formatVergangene[j][0]==="--" || formatVergangene[j][0]===""){
              arrayUebertragVergangene.push(arraychargenwechselVergangene[0][j]);            
            }
            else{
              arraychargenwechselVergangene[0][j];
              var moment = arraychargenwechselVergangene[0][j];
              moment = +moment;
              moment++;
              arrayUebertragVergangene.push([moment]);          
            }
          }
          //Ausgabe    
      var uebertragFormatundChargenwechselVergangene = anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(4,12,15,1);
      uebertragFormatundChargenwechselVergangene.setValues(arrayUebertragVergangene);
      anzeigeTaeglicheZahlen.getRange(22,24,15,1).setValues(arrayUebertragVergangene);      
      var aktuelleZahlenEingabe = dateneingabe.getRange(8,10,15,1).getValues();
  var i = 8;
  while(i<=773){
    var kwAuswertung = auswertung.getRange(i,3,1,1).getValue();
    if(anzeigeKWaktuell === kwAuswertung){
      var aktuelleWocheAuswertung  = auswertung.getRange(i,6,15,1).setValues(aktuelleZahlenEingabe);     
      break;
    }
    else{
      i= i + 15;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you look at the Activity dashboard and check that everything is fine ? [Here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7378739) are instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Sadly its not available in my company..

Comment: As it says [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822): `Up to 100 people with view, edit, or comment permissions can work on a Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides file at the same time`. Check that the triggers are executing properly and are not duplicated. You can do it inside the Apps Script IDE at `Executions` and `Triggers` tabs. Also try making a copy of the file to check if the problem persists.

Comment: The triggers are fine, no duplicate. The execution of some scripts bring an error message from time to time: "Exception: Zu viele gleichzeitige Aufrufe: Tabellen" which translate to: "Exception: Too many simultaneous acceses: Sheets" Somehow if I trigger the functions manually this error does never appear.

Comment: Have you tried to make a copy of the sheet and check if the error persists?

Comment: The problem is, I am pretty sure the error would not persist, because the sheet was running fine for like half a year. And the initial problem is only temporarily, so it comes and goes. And it would be a lot of work to set up the triggers for the copy :P

Comment: To debug your problem, you need to check all the possibilities. By making a copy, you can have better bug isolation. What `Trigger` or function is causing the `Exception: Too many...`?

Comment: Its two different functions with the same error, ill provide the code in the inittial Question. @Emel

Comment: The problem resides is things like `while (i <= 773)`, you are making more than 60 API calls in the second and more than 40 in the first. You should rewrite your code so as not to make so many calls, if you follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) you will see the quotas of the Apps Sript services.

Comment: That is very useful to know, but what part causes the error in the first function? Thanks for your time spend so far with my problem btw :) @Emel

Comment: You are doing too many calls in general, the first thing you have to check are the `while`, then all the calls of the type `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Anzeige 8Wochen-Schnitt").get ... `replace them with something like `let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Anzeige 8Wochen-Schnitt"); ss.get..`.

Comment: @Emel Hi again, i changed all variables (see above functions updated) but i have not found a way to change the while. What exactly is the problem? Its while i<= 773 but i goes up by 15 for each iteration, which lets it run through the while for maximum 52 times, is that really too much? I mean i would be able to change it to a for loop but woud that change anything?